# ReloadData (UITableView) doesn't work

Tags: ios, uitableview, plist, reloaddata

I got a big problem.

```
[self.tableView reloadData];
```

Doesn't work, and I don't understand why.

```
[[self tableView] reloadData];
```

Doesn't work too.

Here is my code:

.h

```
@interface ArticleViewController : UITableViewController <UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate> 
{ 
} 
@end
```

.m

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];
self.tableView.dataSource = self;
self.tableView.delegate = self;
}

btnLeft = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"btnLeft"]
                                         style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain
                                        target:self
                                        action:@selector(loadPlist)];
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = btnLeft;
```

In the `loadPlist` method, I'm writing in a .plist file. This part work fine.

Once all is write in the .plist file :

```
btnRight = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"btnRight"]
                                          style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain
                                         target:self
                                         action:@selector(reloadTheTB)];
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = btnRight;

- (void)reloadTheTB {
NSLog(@"Test reloadTheTB");

[[self tableView] reloadData];
}
```

If I touch `btnRight`, I can see in the log "`Test reloadTheTB`".

Here is `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:`

```
// Customize the appearance of table view cells.
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

        if(cell == nil)
            cell = [self getCellContentView:CellIdentifier];

        contentDictio = [dict objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

        UILabel *lblTemp1 = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:1];

        lblTemp1.text = [contentDictio objectForKey:@"title"];

        if(indexPath.row % 2) {
            UIView* myBackgroundView = [[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero] autorelease];
            myBackgroundView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"cell_grise"]];
            cell.backgroundView = myBackgroundView;
        }
        else {
            UIView* myBackgroundView = [[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero] autorelease];
            myBackgroundView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"cell_blanche"]];
            cell.backgroundView = myBackgroundView;
        }
    }

    return cell;
}
```

**UPDATE:**

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
// Return the number of sections.
return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [dict count];
}
```

Help me please...

Comment: where you have created tableview????

Comment: So what are the changes you are doing which aren't reflected by `[tableView reloadData]`

Comment: It's a `UITableViewController` so, I don't need to create tableView

Comment: The changes are news entries in the plist file

Comment: where is the delegate methods for row and sections????

Comment: Can you show us the `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:`? What looks like is happening is that the model you get the data from in `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` to populate the cells is not updated by writing the .plist file or whatever you are doing.

Comment: actually it will be more interesting to see how you update your datasources. can you paste the code of your delegates methods (numberOfRowsInsection and numberOfSectionsInTableview).

Comment: have you implemented the getCellContentView method?

Comment: @KassemBagher Yes `- (UITableViewCell *) getCellContentView:(NSString *)cellIdentifier`

Comment: can you try to put this line NSLog(@"in cell for row"); inside the cellForRowAtIndexPath method. and see if it's been called

Comment: The way how you implemented the code does not require any IBOutlet connection. I'm just asking if you are adding a UITableView in the view?

Answer (score 0):

Actually I'm wondering this how you know that reloadData is not called?

Try to put some log in cellForRowAtIndexPath? to see if is called or not when you click your button? and also in do this :

```
- (void)reloadTheTB {
   NSLog(@"Test reloadTheTB");
   NSLog(@"%@",dict);
  [[self tableView] reloadData];
```

}

Is the content of your dictionary what you expect? or is not changed after loadPlist?

Probably the call to reloadData is not executed on the main thread and you can update the UI only on the main thread. Try to execute your method on the main thread doing something like this :

```
-(void)ReloadTheTB{   
  [self.tableView performSelectorOnMainThread@selector(reloadData) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:NO]
}
```

Comment: The content of the plist what I expect. 
If I do a `NSLog(@"%@", dict)` in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` I got all my dictionary.

If I do `NSLog(@"%@", dict);` in `- (void)reloadTheTB` there's just `(  )` in the log...

I really don't understand what's happen

Comment: The goal is to understand if you see the log message that you put in cellForRowAtIndexPath after you call reloadData. did you see the log message or not?